# why AVFrame pts value doesn't affect bitrate of frames?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, libav, libavcodec

I'm trying code realtime screen sharing I noticed H264 codec doesn't do constant time encode for every frame. That causes being not able to encode exact same amount frame rate with context->time_base. When we encode less frames per second than time_base bitrate of second becomes lower than what we set.

I modified libav's example encode code and put 1/1000 time base and supply it with only 10 frame. I increase frame->pts related with time_base but bitrates still stay at low.

For results I just change `context->time_base` to {1, 1000}, {1, 10} etc

1/1000 time base (as sum 1989 bytes per second):

```
encoded frame 0 (size=1169)
encoded frame 100 (size=95)
encoded frame 200 (size=92)
encoded frame 300 (size=102)
encoded frame 400 (size=90)
encoded frame 500 (size=90)
encoded frame 600 (size=90)
encoded frame 700 (size=83)
encoded frame 800 (size=95)
encoded frame 900 (size=83)
```

1/10 time base (as sum 95324 bytes per second):

```
encoded frame 0 (size=14187)
encoded frame 1 (size=6053)
encoded frame 2 (size=8530)
encoded frame 3 (size=9277)
encoded frame 4 (size=9508)
encoded frame 5 (size=11163)
encoded frame 6 (size=9685)
encoded frame 7 (size=9346)
encoded frame 8 (size=7662)
encoded frame 9 (size=9913)
```

code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>

static void encode(AVCodecContext *context, AVFrame *frame, AVPacket *pkt, FILE *outfile){
    int ret = avcodec_send_frame(context, frame);
    assert(ret >= 0);
    while(ret >= 0){
        ret = avcodec_receive_packet(context, pkt);
        if(ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF)
            return;
        else if(ret < 0)
            assert(0);
        printf("encoded frame %lld (size=%d)\n", pkt->pts, pkt->size);
        fwrite(pkt->data, 1, pkt->size, outfile);
        av_packet_unref(pkt);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc <= 1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <output file>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET);
    const char *filename = argv[1];
    const AVCodec *codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    assert(codec);
    AVCodecContext *context = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    assert(context);
    AVFrame *frame = av_frame_alloc();
    assert(frame);
    AVPacket *pkt = av_packet_alloc();
    assert(pkt);
    context->bit_rate = 800000;
    context->width = 1280;
    context->height = 720;
    context->time_base = (AVRational){1, 1000};
    context->pix_fmt = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    AVDictionary *dict = 0;
    assert(av_dict_set(&dict, "preset", "veryfast", 0) >= 0);
    assert(av_dict_set(&dict, "tune", "zerolatency", 0) >= 0);
    assert(avcodec_open2(context, codec, &dict) >= 0);
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "wb");
    assert(f);
    frame->format = context->pix_fmt;
    frame->width  = context->width;
    frame->height = context->height;
    assert(av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0) >= 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        for(int y = 0; y < context->height; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < context->width; x++){
                frame->data[0][y * frame->linesize[0] + x] = x + y + i * 3;
            }
        }
        for(int y = 0; y < context->height / 2; y++){
            for(int x = 0; x < context->width / 2; x++){
                frame->data[1][y * frame->linesize[1] + x] = 128 + y + i * 2;
                frame->data[2][y * frame->linesize[2] + x] = 64 + x + i * 5;
            }
        }
        frame->pts = i * (context->time_base.den / 10);
        encode(context, frame, pkt, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
    avcodec_free_context(&context);
    av_frame_free(&frame);
    av_packet_free(&pkt);
    return 0;
}
```

How we can keep right bitrate with different time_base than frame rate?